# Why is tension constant in a massless rope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118905/tension-in-an-atwoods-machine-conceptual) does a good job explaining why tension is the same. However, I don't understand the part when he says:

> "This upward movement would relax the tension in the upper part of the rope ($T_t$ decreases) and increase the tension in the lower part of the rope ($T_b$ increases). This will continue until $T_t$ equals $T_b$ and there is no net force on the rope".

Why does the movement of the rope segment, altering its location, have an affect on the T<sub>b</sub> and T<sub>t</sub>. Shouldn't the two tensions be constant no matter where they are in the system. Why does T<sub>t</sub> moving up lower/relax its tension? And why does T<sub>b</sub> moving up increase its tension.

Comment: I fixed that and the missing quotation markup, and replaced that hacky html subscritps with MathJax.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308011/

Comment: It should be an enough argument that  $T_t-T_b=ma=0$ thus $T_t=T_b$

Comment: I'd appreciate something more in depth and related to my question.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156413/2451 and links therein.