# What is the molecular explanation of a common tension in an ideal rope even when two unequal forces are applied at the two ends of the rope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, free-body-diagram, string

I'm confused with the concept of tension in strings/rope. I have read that tension is an electrostatic force and is created due to the attractive forces by the particles.

I can easily make out that when two equal forces are acting at the two ends of an ideal rope the tension is equal to that applied force, but, what happens when two unequal forces say F1 and F2 are acting at the two ends of the wire, why does the tension produced in the wire lies between the values of F1 and F2?

More specifically if we consider any arbitrary particle on the string won't there be unequal forces at the two ends of the particle(i.e. F1 and F2). According to me, the tension should be the result of the two unequal forces.
Seeking an answer which involves an explanation of the phenomena in the atomic scale.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156413/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426027/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The premise itself is incorrect, there is actually a tension gradient as we move alogn the rope.

Answer (score 0):

When two unequal tensions $T_1>T_2$ are applied at opposite ends   of a  rope of total mass $M$ it will accelerate in the direction of the larger pull  at $a = (T_1-T_2)/M$.

After the comment of R. W Bird I will add what he is saying in equations: At any  point midway between the ends, the tension $T(x)$ will be changing according
$$
\frac {dT}{dx}= \rho a= \rho (T_1-T_2)/M
$$ where $\rho$ is the mass per unit length so that
$$
T_1-T_2= \int_{x_2}^{x_1}   \frac {dT}{dx} dx =\frac{T_1-T_2}{M}\int_{x_2}^{x_1} \rho dx.
$$

The acceleration of each piece of rope is the same, ($a$) and for each piece of rope this acceleration is the difference of the ($x$-dependent) tensions at its ends divided by the  mass of the piece of rope.

Hopefully the use of (atomic scale infinitesimals!) calculus makes it all clear...

Comment: this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: i request u to analyse my question again..i want to know the cause of tension at the atomic level

Comment: Starting at the end with the lower force, at each point in the accelerating rope, the tension must be large enough to accelerate the mass of rope that lies “behind”.

Comment: @R.W.Bird   What about an ideal rope(massless)? I suppose in that case the tension has to remain constant throughout to satisfy newton's 2nd law (net force acting on a massless string must be 0 otherwise there would be infinite acceleration)....but i don't understand how does this go with unequal forces applied at the two ends...i mean how are these two different forces converted into a constant tension throughout the massless string. Please help.

Comment: Indeed:  massles rope will accelerate infinitle rapidy if $T_1\ne T_2$. Therefore the  things applying the tension adjust infinitely rapidly until $T_1=T_2$.

Comment: @mikestone,can you explain the part"things applying tension would adjust infinitely rapidly,more clearly,what doest it mean to adjust here?please explain it with example,so it might help me and OP a lot